# Understanding non-commutativity of tensor product when tensors are interpreted as R-valued linear maps

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

In the textbook *Geometric Control of Mechanical Systems* by Francesco Bullo and Andrew D. Lewis, I find the following:

[image]

I am struggling to reconcile the definition of the tensor product given here with the statement that the tensor product is *not* commutative. It appears that the tensor product is defined by multiplying the image of $t_1$ with the image of $t_2$ (i.e. multiplying a real number by a real number) but isn't multiplication on the real numbers commutative?

I have a hypothesis and my goal with this question is to confirm whether it is correct. My hypothesis as to why these two facts agree is that $t_1 \otimes t_2$ and $t_2 \otimes t_1$ are different tensors (e.g. they have different components) but given the same inputs and somehow keeping track of which inputs went to $t_1$ and $t_2$, they both map to the same real number.

In other words, in the case where $t_1 \in T^1_0(V)$ and $t_2 \in T^0_1(V)$ then $t_1 \otimes t_2, t_2 \otimes t_1 \in T^1_1(V)$ can be thought of as 2D matrices given a basis on V. These matrices have the same components, but they are rearranged such that the inputs are, for lack of better phrasing, still being fed to their corresponding tensor. Therefore $t_1 \otimes t_2$ and $t_2 \otimes t_1$ are different tensors (their components are not the same), but the real number to which they are mapping a particular vector and covector input stays the same in some sense.

My background is in mechanical engineering and I never had the privilege of a proper course in multilinear algebra.

Comment: For a simple example consider the outer product of two column vectors $u$ and $v$ and we can easily see that $uv^T \neq vu^T$.

Comment: Tensor products are multivariable  functions. Nothing commutes on this level. Multilinear functions  means,  sums in any one argument are expanded into sums of tensor products and all numeric factors can be gathered as prefactors until only non-reducible basis vectors remain as argument.  Symmetry only comes into  the game, if two aruments are filled with the same basis vector, then there are two possibilities: Output res=0 ()<antisymmetric or <> 0 (symmetric). By dualisation, the tensor product of vectors are defined as multilinear functions on the linear forms. Same game.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are overthinking this. Just apply the definition. If we want
$$
  t_1\otimes t_2 \overset?= t_2\otimes t_1
$$
then that means we need
$$
  (t_1\otimes t_2)(v,w) \overset?= (t_2\otimes t_1)(v,w)
$$
for all vectors $v,w$, and applying the definition of the tensor product shows that we need
$$
  t_1(v)t_2(w) \overset?= t_2(v)t_1(w).
$$
What reason is there for these two expressions to be equal?

Now, if we choose a vector basis $e_i$ then multilinearity tells us that tensors are determined by there values on this basis. So define
$$
  T_{ij} = (t_1\otimes t_2)(e_i, e_j),\quad S_{ij} = (t_2\otimes t_1)(e_i, e_j).
$$
It's easy enough to see that $T_{ij} = S_{ji}$, but this doesn't mean that they are the same tensor anymore than a matrix is the same as its transpose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I suppose the root of my confusion still lies in how we know $t_1(v)t_2(w)\stackrel{?}{=}t_2(v)t_1(w)$ must be the case. I think this is what my intuition is trying to get at when I said "keep track of which input goes to which tensor" above. The idea that the inputs would need to be swapped if the tensors were swapped makes sense to me for this specific example, but it isn't clear to me what's going on in general when each tensor has a different number of inputs which may be different combinations of vectors/covectors.

Comment: For example, if $t_1 \in T_2^0(V)$ and $t_2 \in T_0^1(V)$, then what goes into the tensors in the right side here: $t_1(v, w)t_2(\alpha)\stackrel{?}{=}t_2(?)t_1(?)$. This seems strange because we would be feeding the wrong number of inputs or the wrong type of object into each tensor. $t_2$ only accepts one covector, not two vectors.

Comment: @AdamSperry It seems your actual confusion is just in reading the definition as presented. That's "how we know"; it's just what the definition says. What the definition says is that if $T \in T^p_q(V)$ and $S \in T^r_s(V)$ then $T\otimes S \in T^{p+r}_{q+s}(V)$ and is defined so that its arguments "distribute" between $T$ and $S$ *in that order*. So in your example $$(t_1\otimes t_2)(\alpha, v, w) = t_1(v,w)t_2(\alpha)$$ and $$(t_2\otimes t_1)(\alpha, v, w) = t_2(\alpha)t_1(v,w).$$

Comment: So it turns out these are the same; this is actually because the "tensor product" defined isn't quite a "true" tensor product, in the sense that it doese't allow for forms like $V\otimes V\otimes V^*$ or $V\otimes V^*\otimes V$ and instead collapses both to $V^*\otimes V\otimes V$. A "true" tensor product would have $$(t_1\otimes t_2)(v, w, \alpha) = t_1(v,w)t_2(\alpha)$$ and $$(t_2\otimes t_1)(\alpha, v, w) = t_2(\alpha)t_1(v,w).$$ Notice the order of the arguments, and that these aren't even the same *type* of function.